# Accessibility: Spinner Status Messages Guidelines

Tags: wai-aria, voiceover, talkback, nvda, accessible

### Scenario

Using a screen reader such as NVDA, VoiceOver, or TalkBack, after all dropdown selections are made, show loading spinner overlay while data is retrieved from the server.

### Question

First I want to mention that this is a high level question and am looking for advice or resources to help make the best educated decision. Based on my understanding, it is important to let Screen Reader users (SR) know that this loading is occurring and to also mention when it is finished. [WCAG 4.1.3 Status Messages](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/status-messages). Is it acceptable to have a generic message such as "Content Loading" and "Content Finished Loading" or should it be as specific as possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be specific on the type of data that's loading unless it makes sense to do so. If I'm on a restaurant site and type in a zipcode, it *could* say "loading restaurant locations nearby" but could just as easily say "loading".  The user just typed in a zipcode and clicked on "search" (or something similar) so it seems kind of obvious that restaurant locations are being loaded and you don't necessarily have to say that.

It's always nice from a UX perspective to have detailed messages but you need to balance that with being too wordy for screen reader users.

If you announce that something is loaded you definitely want to let the user know when it's done.

However, if you don't have any visual indication that something is loading then you don't necessarily have to announce something is loading for the screen reader user.  A sighted user might notice the busy indicator on the browser tab, so they know the page is loading, but you don't have to announce that.  (Ideally, the fact that a page is loading should be announced by the browser itself.)

You didn't ask for specifics but take a look at [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) (and possibly [`aria-atomic`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-atomic) and [`aria-relevant`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-relevant)) for announcing text changes and look at [`aria-busy`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-busy).

Comment: Thanks for this response. It is hard to determine what is expected being new to accessibility and not having real life examples of how it is used with real users. For my case, it is zipcode related and a simple "Loading" and "Loading Complete" status message will do. Thanks for the additional content aria-atomic will help me force the screen reader to announce the entire message again instead of just the appended text.